# Time calculation with SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

In a MySQL calendar, items are placed using start+duration. Both integers, BUT:
Start looks like this: `YYYYMMDDhhmm` while duration is just a number of minutes.

Before inserting a new item I have to ensure it doesn't overlap existing items.
**The hard part**: Is any existing item's start+duration > the my new items start.
In SQL:  Calculate `(YYYYMMDDhhmm + minutes)` and return a valid `YYYYMMDDhhmm`
**This helps**: `start+duration` will **never** cause the `YYYYMMDD-part` to change : )

*Thank to everybody - my (PHP) implementation:*

```
$exists = runSQL("SELECT id FROM cal ".
    "WHERE  STR_TO_DATE(start,'%Y%m%d%H%i') + INTERVAL duration MINUTE ".
    "       > ".
    "       STR_TO_DATE( ? ,'%Y%m%d%H%i') ".
    "  AND  STR_TO_DATE(start,'%Y%m%d%H%i') ".
    "       < ".
    "       STR_TO_DATE( ? ,'%Y%m%d%H%i') + INTERVAL ? MINUTE"
    ,array("iii", $start, $start, $minutes ));
if (count($exists) > 0) bitch("Too late - Update your view");
```

Works perfectly BUT invokes `STR_TO_DATE()` 4 times..

Thanks to Spencer7593: A much faster (and shorter) version:

```
$exists = runSQL("SELECT id FROM cal ".
    "WHERE  start*100 + INTERVAL duration MINUTE > ?*100 + INTERVAL 0 MINUTE ".
    "  AND  start*100 + INTERVAL 0 MINUTE        < ?*100 + INTERVAL ? MINUTE"
    ,array("iii", $start, $start, $minutes ));
if (count($exists) > 0) bitch("Too late, slot taken - Update your view");
```

Comment: Sooooo....what's your question?

Comment: How to (YYYYMMDDhhmm + minutes) and return a valid YYYYMMDDhhmm (in SQL)

Comment: How do you think `start+duration` will never cause the `yyyymmdd` part to change? If your date is `201403162355` and you want to add `5` or more minutes, it sure will affect a date change.

Comment: @Ravinder: Yes but that WILL NOT HAPPEN - items NEVER cross midnight

Comment: @T4NK3R - I'd never rely on that, just in case.  Also, that's a terrible way to store date/time information.  You should be using one of the built-in timestamp types (MySQL has several), if for no other reason than to prevent incorrect values.  If it must be an `INTEGER` field, store it as an offset from some point in time (the standard is usually the Unix Epoch - `1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC`).  Note that this will actually give you a larger range of representable dates.

Comment: @Muse: Thank you for the concern. I DO use proper times (UTC even) for created/modified and such. Not for the calendar entries themselves. I find this format more convenient.. (for information-bearing DOM-ID's - without conversion). As for relying on validity: I check them before insertion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to convert to a DATETIME, from integer "start" representation YYYYMMDDHHMM and adding an integer "duration" in minutes, is to just add a seconds portion (change from 12 digits to 14 digits) by multiplying by 100, and then add an interval, and MySQL will implicitly convert the integer value to DATETIME. For example:

```
 t.start*100 + INTERVAL t.duration MINUTE
```

To convert just the "start" without adding a "duration", do it exactly the same way, except specify a literal `0` in place of `t.duration`. For example:

```
 t.start*100 + INTERVAL 0 MINUTE
```

---

**FOLLOWUP**

**Q:** Does this implicitly convert to string and call STR_TO_DATE, requiring "more computing" than using STR_TO_DATE?

**A:** I don't believe it does. Performance test results demonstrate significantly faster without the STR_TO_DATE function; which likely means it's actually a shorter code path.

Query 1: implicit conversion of integer to DATETIME

```
SELECT /*!40001 SQL_NO_CACHE */ t.start
  FROM demo0317 t
 WHERE ( t.start*100 + INTERVAL t.duration MINUTE ) 
     = STR_TO_DATE('2014-03-17 09:39','%Y-%m-%d %h:%i')
```

Query 2: conversion of integer to DATETIME using STR_TO_DATE

```
SELECT /*!40001 SQL_NO_CACHE */ t.start
  FROM demo0317 t
 WHERE ( STR_TO_DATE(t.start,'%Y%m%d%h%i') + INTERVAL t.duration MINUTE ) 
     = STR_TO_DATE('2014-03-17 09:39','%Y-%m-%d %h:%i')
```

Query elapsed times:

```
run  Query 1    Query 2
---  ---------  ----------
 2:  8.129 sec  15.520 sec
 3:  8.124 sec  15.625 sec
 4:  8.125 sec  15.622 sec
 5:  8.123 sec  15.626 sec
---  ---------  ----------
avg  8.125 sec  15.598 sec
```

Comment: or WILL it bypass string-handling altogether ?

Comment: No it can't. First it will see it's not, then convert it, and THEN use STR_TO_DATE = more computing. But nice short source code : )

Comment: Great followup. I'll use this method instead!

Comment: @T4NK3R: The big advantage of the STR_TO_DATE is flexibility; it can convert to DATETIME from a wide variety of string formats" various delimiters, one digit day, spelled out month names, components in different order, etc. The implicit conversion from integer is much more strict, in how many decimal digits and how those digits are interpreted.

Comment: yes much faster. AND the source is shorter and more readable : )

Answer (score 1):

> *How to (YYYYMMDDhhmm + minutes) and return a valid YYYYMMDDhhmm (in SQL)?*

One way to do it

```
SELECT t.*, 
       1 * DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(start, '%Y%m%d%H%i') + 
                       INTERVAL duration MINUTE, '%Y%m%d%H%i') end
  FROM table_name t
```

or without string manipulation

```
SELECT t.*,
       FLOOR(start / 10000) * 10000 + 
         FLOOR(start MOD 10000 / 100) * 100 + 
           FLOOR((start MOD 100 + duration) / 60) * 100 + 
             (start MOD 100 + duration) MOD 60 end
  FROM calendar t
```

Sample output for both cases:

```
| ID |        START | DURATION |          END |
|----|--------------|----------|--------------|
|  1 | 201403151200 |       60 | 201403151300 |
|  1 | 201403161545 |       35 | 201403161620 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dbcaea/1)** demo

Comment: You're clearly a master! But I'm afraid the string-free version gets a bit too long-haired for me to maintain.. I WILL test it in a loop though, to see if the speed gain justifies the "greek" : )

Comment: Something is wrong.. I set end into a @variable - looks OK (201408161200) - but when I compare it in WHERE it's bigger than 201308160000 (2013) but smaller than 201408160000 ?!? Like there's some integer overflow..?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `STR_TO_DATE` function on your string formatted datetime values.

**Example**:

```
mysql> select @ts:=str_to_date( '201403161155','%Y%m%d%h%i' ) ts,
    -> @ts + interval 5 minute 'add 5 min';
+---------------------+---------------------+
| ts                  | add 5 min           |
+---------------------+---------------------+
| 2014-03-16 11:55:00 | 2014-03-16 12:00:00 |
+---------------------+---------------------+
```

And using `DATE_FORMAT` function on the returned datetime, you re-apply `'%Y%m%d%h%i'` to match your data format.

```
mysql> select @ts:=str_to_date( '201403161155','%Y%m%d%h%i' ) ts,
    -> @nts:=(@ts + interval 5 minute) 'add 5 min',
    -> date_format( @nts, '%Y%m%d%h%i' ) nts;
+---------------------+---------------------+--------------+
| ts                  | add 5 min           | nts          |
+---------------------+---------------------+--------------+
| 2014-03-16 11:55:00 | 2014-03-16 12:00:00 | 201403161200 |
+---------------------+---------------------+--------------+
```

Comment: You were first with the `str_to_date('201403161155','%Y%m%d%h%i') + interval 5 minute` which gave me the solution - the checkmark is yours : )

Comment: For the benefit of future readers: it's not entirely accurate to say that you "**need** to use the STR_TO_DATE function". That function can be used, as demonstrated in this answer. But STR_TO_DATE is not strictly necessary. And it's not the most efficient alternative.

Comment: @spencer7593: You are right. `replace(answer, 'need to', 'can')`

Comment: Sorry Ravinder - you're not wrong, but Spencer deserves the checkmark instead.

Comment: @T4NK3R: NP. His explanation is broader on the solution.